# IE7-8 issue with jQuery click

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I'm really just lost as to why IE would throw a fit. It works in Chrome and IE9. Here's my script:

```
var utilityNav = function() {
$('#head-nav a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#head-nav a').removeClass('head-link-active').next('div').removeClass('shadow').slideUp('fast').css('z-index', '7999');
    if ($(this).next('div').is(':hidden')) {
        var linkPos = $(this).position().left + $(this).width()/2 + 4;
        $(this).addClass('head-link-active');
        $(this).next('div').addClass('shadow').slideDown().css('left', linkPos + 'px').css('z-index', '8000');
    }
});
$('.utility-three').children('.utility-three-block').eq(1).addClass('borders');
};
```

I don't think anything is syntactically wrong with it, but I'd really appreciate some help. Thanks.

Comment: What's in `shadow`,`borders`,`head-link-active` classes? What styles do you use in them? Show us your `css`.

Comment: Sorry, I had a buddy looking at it, so I couldn't respond. The issue it throws is : 
SCRIPT87: Invalid argument. 
jquery-1.7.2.js, line 8988 character 5

Comment: We figured out that it's part of the slideUp and slideDown functions, but I still don't know why it would be an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up being a code conflict with bxSlider. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

the problem is very likely with the line,

`e.preventDefault()`

for IE, you will also need to add,

`event.returnValue = false;`